# ADODB.Stream alternative for large images

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

Need to find an alternative to using ADODB.Stream as it will load the entire file into memory and with file sizes over 200MB and simultaneous downloads can easily run out of memory.

The only thing I can find to do would be to either rewrite in ASP.Net or write our own COM component that wouldn't load the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ADODB.Stream actually does read the whole file into memory, it will use a .tmp file in the Temporary directory.  However it still isn't the most desirable approach.

In the past I've build my own VB6 component to create an IStream implementation on top of the WinAPI having done extensive searching for such an alternative and finding nothing.

One option you have instead of a complete re-write to ASP.NET would be to create a .NET COM component to handle pumping stream to a file.